# Why does the C code produce bus error？

Tags: c

The following code is used to reverse C style String.But when I run this code,

it produce the error:

> [1]    42496 bus error  ./a.out

and I don't know how to solve this problem. Could you please help me? Thank you in

advance:)

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  void reverse(char * str){
           char * end = str;
           char tmp;
           if(str){
               while(*end){
                   ++end;
               }
              --end;
              while(str<end){
                  tmp = *str;
                  *str++ = *end;
                  *end-- = tmp;
              }
          }
  }
  int main(){
      char * str = "abcd";
      reverse(str);
      printf("%s\n",str);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 char * str = "abcd";
```

This is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) , you cannot modify  it . It is a constant. As in your function `reverse` you try to modify it therefore , you get an error.

Instead declare like this -

```
 char str[] = "abcd";
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/YfmBzT)

Comment: Detail: a string literal  may/may not be modifiable.  Attempting to modify it is UB.

Answer (score 0):

type `list -l` and check file permissions.
btw, compiled and run on my windows machine using `gcc`